# Como enviar e processar N formulários distintos com ajax sem dar refresh na pagina?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Como fazer quando se tem N formulários com mesmo `ID`, ou `CLASS` enviar os dados (*submit*) processar e quando terminar o processamento mudar a cor da `<'tr bgcolor="#FFFF00"'>` 
para verde `'#00FF00'` sinalizando que foi finalizado o processo.
Obs. Tudo isto tem que acontecer sem dar *refresh* (sem atualizar) na pagina e utilizando [php](/questions/tagged/php).

```
    <table width="900" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFF00">
            <td>
                <form id="NOME-PADRÃO">
                    <fieldset>
                        nome:
                      <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
                        e-mail
                        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        <input type="submit" id="enviar" placeholder="Enviar" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>    
            </td>
      </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFF00">
            <td>
                <form id="NOME-PADRÃO">
                    <fieldset>
                        nome:
                      <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
                        e-mail
                        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        <input type="submit" id="enviar" placeholder="Enviar" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>    
            </td>
      </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFF00">
            <td>
                <form id="NOME-PADRÃO">
                    <fieldset>
                        nome:
                      <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
                        e-mail
                        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        <input type="submit" id="enviar" placeholder="Enviar" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>    
            </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Você não pode ter elementos diferentes com o mesmo `id`! Use `class` para isso.

Comment: Não é MUITO mais elegante você ter a listagem dos dados e em seguida um único formulário (ou vice-versa), com um único conjunto de campos a serem preenchidos e submetidos com AJAX e, em caso de sucesso, os valores dos campos seriam limpos e a TR mudaria de cor? Dessa forma sua aplicação funciona com e sem AJAX, sem obstrusão. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sup>Em primeiro lugar, você não pode ter múltiplos elementos com o mesmo `id`, como comentou o @Andrey acima. Corrija isso no seu HTML ou ele será inválido (fora os problemas que você terá ao tentar localizar esses elementos repetidos por id). Você pode substituir os ids por classes.</sup>

---

É simples submeter todos os formulários por Ajax, com ajuda do método [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) do jQuery, que varre um formulário e coleta os valores dos campos. O exemplo abaixo utiliza [Promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) para detectar quando tudo estiver concluído.

```
var promessas = [];
var url = "url_do_seu_php";
$("form").each(function(){
  var dados = $(this).serialize();
  promessas.push($.post(url, dados));
});
$.when.apply($, promessas).done(function(){
  // todos os formulários foram processados
});
```